# onIceCandidate method never called

Tags: android, socket.io, webrtc, android-jetpack-compose

I am working with WebRTC on jetpack compose using socket io, an offer comes to me from the server for a video call with the user and I save it as remoteDescription, then I create my answer for this offer, save it as localDescription and send the answer to the user, I do everything done from the operator side. The user, in turn, before sending the offer, saves it as localDescription, and my answer as RemoteDescription. And logically, after the user and I have saved the localDescription, we should exchange iceCandidae. But instead, my own iceCandidate is not created and the onIceCandidate method is not called, but everything works fine for the user. If anyone knows the reason please help me!

my RTCClient class:

```
import org.webrtc.*
import org.webrtc.Logging.Severity
import org.webrtc.PeerConnection.IceServer
import org.webrtc.PeerConnection.Observer
import org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper.create

class RTCClient(
    private val context: Context,
) {

    companion object {
        private val TAG = RTCClient::class.java.simpleName
    }

    val eglContext = EglBase.create()

    private val peerConnectionFactory by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        createPeerConnectionFactory()
    }

    private var peerConnection: PeerConnection? = null
//    by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
//
//    }

    private val sdpObserver = InnerSdpObserver()

    private var localStream: MediaStream? = null
    private var remoteStream: MediaStream? = null

    private val videoCapturer by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "getVideoCapturer()")

        Camera2Enumerator(context).run {
            deviceNames.find { isFrontFacing(it) }?.let {
                createCapturer(it, object : CameraVideoCapturer.CameraEventsHandler {
                    override fun onFirstFrameAvailable() {

                    }

                    override fun onCameraOpening(p0: String?) {

                    }

                    override fun onCameraFreezed(p0: String?) {

                    }

                    override fun onCameraError(p0: String?) {

                    }

                    override fun onCameraDisconnected() {

                    }

                    override fun onCameraClosed() {

                    }
                })
            } ?: throw IllegalStateException()
        }
    }

    private val localAudioSource by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(MediaConstraints().apply {
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googEchoCancellation", "true"))
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googEchoCancellation2", "true"))
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googAutoGainControl", "true"))
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googAutoGainControl2", "true"))
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googNoiseSuppression", "true"))
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googNoiseSuppression2", "true"))
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googHighpassFilter", "true"))
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googAudioMirroring", "false"))
        })
    }

    private val localVideoSource by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(false)
    }

    private var surfaceViewCallback: SurfaceViewCallback? = null

    private var localSessionDescription: SessionDescription? = null
    private var remoteSessionDescription: SessionDescription? = null

    var currentSubscriber: String? = null

    private val observer = object : Observer {
        override fun onSignalingChange(p0: PeerConnection.SignalingState?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onSignalingChange() -> $p0")
        }

        override fun onIceConnectionChange(p0: PeerConnection.IceConnectionState?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onIceConnectionChange() -> $p0")
        }

        override fun onStandardizedIceConnectionChange(newState: PeerConnection.IceConnectionState?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onStandardizedIceConnectionChange() -> $newState")
        }

        override fun onConnectionChange(newState: PeerConnection.PeerConnectionState?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onConnectionChange() -> $newState")
        }

        override fun onIceConnectionReceivingChange(p0: Boolean) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onIceConnectionReceivingChange() -> $p0")
        }

        override fun onIceGatheringChange(p0: PeerConnection.IceGatheringState?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onIceGatheringChange() -> $p0")
        }

        override fun onIceCandidate(p0: IceCandidate?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onIceCandidate -> $p0")

//            addIceCandidate(p0)

            socketClient.sendRtcMessage(
                candidate = p0?.sdp,
                type = "candidate",
                user = currentSubscriber,
                label = p0?.sdpMLineIndex,
                id = p0?.sdpMid
            )
        }

        override fun onIceCandidatesRemoved(p0: Array<out IceCandidate>?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onIceCandidatesRemoved() -> $p0")
        }

        override fun onSelectedCandidatePairChanged(event: CandidatePairChangeEvent?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onSelectedCandidatePairChanged() -> $event")
        }

        override fun onAddStream(p0: MediaStream?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onAddStream() -> $p0")

            surfaceViewCallback?.onAddRemoteStream(p0)
        }

        override fun onRemoveStream(p0: MediaStream?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onRemoveStream() -> $p0")

//            surfaceViewCallback?.onRemoveRemoteStream(p0)
        }

        override fun onDataChannel(p0: DataChannel?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onDataChannel() -> $p0")
        }

        override fun onRenegotiationNeeded() {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onRenegotiationNeeded()")
        }

        override fun onRemoveTrack(receiver: RtpReceiver?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Observer#onRemoveTrack() -> $receiver")

//            if (receiver?.track()?.kind() == "video") {
//                surfaceViewCallback?.onRemoveRemoteStream(null)
//            }
        }

        override fun onTrack(transceiver: RtpTransceiver?) {
            Logger.debug(
                TAG,
                "Observer#onTrack() -> ${transceiver?.currentDirection}, ${transceiver?.mid}"
            )
        }
    }

    init {
        initPeerConnectionFactory()
    }

    private fun initPeerConnectionFactory() {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "initPeerConnectionFactory()")

        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(
            PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(context)
                .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
                .setInjectableLogger({ p0, p1, p2 ->
                    Logger.debug(TAG, "Internal: $p0 $p1 $p2")
                }, Severity.LS_WARNING)
                .createInitializationOptions()
        )
        peerConnection = createPeerConnection()
    }

    private fun createPeerConnectionFactory(): PeerConnectionFactory {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "createPeerConnectionFactory()")

        return PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
            .setVideoEncoderFactory(
                DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
                    eglContext.eglBaseContext,
                    true,
                    true
                )
            )
            .setVideoDecoderFactory(
                DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(eglContext.eglBaseContext)
            )
//            .setVideoEncoderFactory(
//                SoftwareVideoEncoderFactory()
//            )
//            .setVideoDecoderFactory(
//                SoftwareVideoDecoderFactory()
//            )
            .setOptions(
                PeerConnectionFactory.Options().apply {
                    disableEncryption = true
                    disableNetworkMonitor = true
                }
            )
            .createPeerConnectionFactory()
    }

    private fun createPeerConnection(): PeerConnection? {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "createPeerConnection()")

        return peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(
            PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers).apply {
                iceTransportsType = PeerConnection.IceTransportsType.ALL
                bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.MAXBUNDLE
                rtcpMuxPolicy = PeerConnection.RtcpMuxPolicy.REQUIRE
                tcpCandidatePolicy = PeerConnection.TcpCandidatePolicy.DISABLED
                continualGatheringPolicy =
                    PeerConnection.ContinualGatheringPolicy.GATHER_CONTINUALLY
            },
            observer
        )
    }

    fun initSurfaceViewCallback(callback: SurfaceViewCallback) {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "initSurfaceViewCallback() -> $callback")

        surfaceViewCallback = callback
    }

    fun startLocalVideo(): MediaStream? {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "startLocalVideo()")

        val surfaceTextureHelper = create("CaptureThread", eglContext.eglBaseContext)
        videoCapturer.initialize(
            surfaceTextureHelper,
            context,
            localVideoSource.capturerObserver
        )
        videoCapturer.startCapture(1280, 720, 30)

        localStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS")

        val localAudioTrack =
            peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("audio_track", localAudioSource)
        localStream?.addTrack(localAudioTrack)

        val localVideoTrack =
            peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("local_track", localVideoSource)
        localStream?.addTrack(localVideoTrack)

        peerConnection?.addStream(localStream)
        return localStream
    }

    fun onRemoteSessionDescriptionReceived(sessionDescription: SessionDescription) {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "onRemoteSessionDescriptionReceived() -> ${sessionDescription.type}")

        var description = CodecUtils.preferCodec(
            sessionDescription.description,
            CodecUtils.AUDIO_CODEC_OPUS,
            true
        )

        description = CodecUtils.preferCodec(
            description,
            CodecUtils.VIDEO_CODEC_VP9,
            false
        )
        remoteSessionDescription = SessionDescription(sessionDescription.type, description)
        peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(
            sdpObserver,
            remoteSessionDescription
        )
    }

    private inner class InnerSdpObserver : SdpObserver {
        override fun onCreateSuccess(sessionDescription: SessionDescription?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "InnerSdpObserver#onCreateSuccess() -> $sessionDescription")

            var description = CodecUtils.preferCodec(
                sessionDescription?.description,
                CodecUtils.AUDIO_CODEC_OPUS,
                true
            )

            description = CodecUtils.preferCodec(
                description,
                CodecUtils.VIDEO_CODEC_VP9,
                false
            )

            localSessionDescription = SessionDescription(sessionDescription?.type, description)

            peerConnection?.setLocalDescription(sdpObserver, localSessionDescription)
        }

        override fun onCreateFailure(p0: String?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "InnerSdpObserver#onCreateFailure() -> $p0")
        }

        override fun onSetSuccess() {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "InnerSdpObserver#onSetSuccess()")

            localSessionDescription?.let {
                if (it.type == SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER) {
                    Logger.debug(TAG, "onSetSuccess() -> createAnswer: $currentSubscriber")
                    socketClient.sendRtcMessage(
                        sdp = it.description,
                        type = "answer",
                        user = currentSubscriber
                    )
                } else if (it.type == SessionDescription.Type.OFFER) {
                    Logger.debug(TAG, "onSetSuccess() -> createOffer: $currentSubscriber")
                    socketClient.sendRtcMessage(
                        sdp = it.description,
                        type = "offer",
                        user = currentSubscriber
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onSetFailure(p0: String?) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "InnerSdpObserver#onSetFailure() -> $p0")
        }
    }

    fun sendOffer() {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "sendOffer()")

        peerConnection?.createOffer(sdpObserver, MediaConstraints().apply {
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"))
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"))
        })
    }

    fun sendAnswer() {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "sendAnswer()")

        peerConnection?.createAnswer(sdpObserver, MediaConstraints().apply {
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"))
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"))
        })
    }

    fun addIceCandidate(iceCandidate: IceCandidate) {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "addIceCandidate() -> $iceCandidate")

        peerConnection?.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate, object : AddIceObserver {
            override fun onAddSuccess() {
                Logger.debug(TAG, "AddIceObserver#onAddSuccess()")
            }

            override fun onAddFailure(p0: String?) {
                Logger.debug(TAG, "AddIceObserver#onAddFailure() -> $p0")
            }
        })
    }

    fun finishPeerConnection() {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "finishPeerConnection()")

        videoCapturer.stopCapture()

        localStream?.let {
            peerConnection?.removeStream(it)
        }

        peerConnection?.dispose()
    }
}


interface SurfaceViewCallback {
    fun onAddRemoteStream(mediaStream: MediaStream?)
    fun onRemoveRemoteStream(mediaStream: MediaStream?)
}
```

this is my messageListener:

```
} else if (jsonObject.has("rtc")) {
    val idChat = jsonObject.getStringOrNull("chat")
    val sender = jsonObject.getStringOrNull("sender")
    val rtcObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("rtc")
    val rtcModel = WebRTCModel.RTCModel(
        type = rtcObject.getStringOrNull("type"),
        sdp = rtcObject.getStringOrNull("sdp"),
        from = rtcObject.getStringOrNull("_from"),
        candidate = rtcObject.getStringOrNull("candidate"),
        id = rtcObject.getStringOrNull("id"),
        label = rtcObject.getIntOrNull("label")
    )
    if (rtcObject.getStringOrNull("type").equals("hangup")) {
        callEndCallback?.callEnd(
            webRTCModel = WebRTCModel(
                chatId = idChat,
                sender = sender,
                rtc = rtcModel
            )
        )
        callPageCallback?.callEnd()
    } else {
        callPageCallback?.onMessage(
            webRTCModel = WebRTCModel(
                chatId = idChat,
                sender = sender,
                rtc = rtcModel
            )
        )
    }
}
```

One more thing iceConnectionChange callback changes to CHECKING after it accepts the user's iceCandidate.
And one more thing, the logs that appeared after receiving the offer may be useful:

```
D/RTCClient: onRemoteSessionDescriptionReceived() -> OFFER
D/RTCClient: Observer#onSignalingChange() -> HAVE_REMOTE_OFFER
D/RTCClient: Internal: (line 329): Elapsed time (163576 ms) longer than expected, limiting to 2000
     LS_WARNING pacing_controller.cc
D/RTCClient: Internal: (line 3446): Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
     LS_ERROR webrtc_video_engine.cc
D/RTCClient: Observer#onAddStream() -> [gre6aHoVs2GaW0CM9m1Ava8gBe0ss2VhPbLY:A=1:V=1]
D/VideoCallComponent: onAddRemoteStream() -> [gre6aHoVs2GaW0CM9m1Ava8gBe0ss2VhPbLY:A=1:V=1]
D/RTCClient: InnerSdpObserver#onSetSuccess()
D/RTCClient: sendAnswer()
D/RTCClient: Internal: (line 936): RED codec red is missing an associated payload type.
     LS_WARNING media_session.cc
D/VideoCallComponent: VideoCall.Model#subscribe() -> Model(localStream=[ARDAMS:A=1:V=1], remoteStream=[gre6aHoVs2GaW0CM9m1Ava8gBe0ss2VhPbLY:A=1:V=1])
D/RTCClient: InnerSdpObserver#onCreateSuccess() -> org.webrtc.SessionDescription@cc58193
D/VideoScreen: model.subscribeAsState() -> Model(localStream=[ARDAMS:A=1:V=1], remoteStream=[gre6aHoVs2GaW0CM9m1Ava8gBe0ss2VhPbLY:A=1:V=1])
E/xoffice.androi: No package ID ff found for ID 0xffffffff.
D/RTCClient: Observer#onSignalingChange() -> STABLE
D/RTCClient: Observer#onRemoveTrack() -> org.webrtc.RtpReceiver@47e13a6
I/SurfaceView: onWindowVisibilityChanged(0) true org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer{c0f21e7 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} of ViewRootImpl@643f65f[MainActivity]
D/RTCClient: Observer#onRemoveTrack() -> org.webrtc.RtpReceiver@2a3f43d
D/RTCClient: InnerSdpObserver#onSetSuccess()
D/RTCClient: onSetSuccess() -> createAnswer: user:ws:d8DHOnpJHYb6FC0VACHr
```

and after saving the answer in setLocalDescription:

D/RTCClient: Observer#onIceConnectionChange() -> CHECKING

The output of iceCandidates in the onIceCandidate method